# Last week: we need more questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, public-beta

The math educators beta has only one more week guaranteed. Over the past 12 weeks, matheducators.SE has done quite well ([details](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64216/mathematics-educators)), for an overview:

We have a very healthy number of enthusiastic and active users who, along with more transient users, have answered 100% of questions!

However, too few new questions are being asked per day. We are now at <strike>2.9</strike> 3.2 questions per day. This is a bit over half the threshold for the "okay" category and well short of the 15 question per day target.

---

$$ \color{blue}{\textbf{Keep asking questions during this (potentially) final week!}} $$

---

Comment: I would definitely like to see more questions per day (and quality answers), but I would not like to have the site swamped in questions. I suspect that too many questions per day can mean that individual questions often do not receive sufficient attention (cf. Mathematics Stack Exchange). I suppose it's about finding the right balance of quantity and quality.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This comes up from time to time, but we don't close down sites at the end of the 90 days and we certainly wouldn't do that *just for low question rates*. That isn't to say we don't want more questions ([we do](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/872/690)). Rather we want people to continue to ask good, answerable questions. Shortly, you should be getting an opportunity to self-evaluate a sample of questions from the site. That should help us narrow down on what to focus on next.